# python logging.config not available?

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

In the tutorial [Good logging practice in Python](https://fangpenlin.com/posts/2012/08/26/good-logging-practice-in-python/) the main module looks for `logging.config` but my python 2.7 installations don't show that when I use `dir(logging)` and when I try to run this example I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/your-name-here/logging python/example.py", line 7, in <module>
logging.config.fileConfig('logging.ini')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'config'
```

`logging.config` certainly shows up in some [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html) so it's not a mistake. Why doesn't it show up in any of my python 2.7 installations (when I type `dir(logging)` including my anaconda from last year, *and how can I get this example to work?*

main.py:

```
import logging

# load my module
import my_module

# load the logging configuration
logging.config.fileConfig('logging.ini')

my_module.foo()
bar = my_module.Bar()
bar.bar()
```

my_module.py:

```
import logging

def foo():
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.info('Hi, foo')

class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self, logger=None):
        self.logger = logger or logging.getLogger(__name__)

    def bar(self):
        self.logger.info('Hi, bar')
```

logging.ini:

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=
```

Comment: Would you happen to have a file named ``logging.py`` in your ``/Users/your-name-here/logging python/`` folder?

Comment: @MikeScotty no I don't but I do have something called `logging python example SE.py`. I'll clean out everything else right now and try again now...  **update:** nope!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to import the module itself not just logging:

```
In [1]: import logging

In [2]: 'config' in dir(logging)
Out[2]: False

In [3]: import logging.config

In [4]: 'config' in dir(logging)
Out[4]: True
```

**Why?**

It looks like it is not a module included when you import the package, since it is not a namespace of `__init__.py` in the logging package, however it is in the directory, hence you can still import it explicitly:

```
> pwd
/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging

ls -1 *py
__init__.py
config.py
handlers.py
```

Comment: Interesting! That certainly generates a whole new list of errors for me, but not the one in question.  This is progress!, but I still need "... *and how can I get this example to work?*" `"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 607, in get
    raise NoSectionError(section)
NoSectionError: No section: 'formatters'`

Comment: thanks, so there is something wrong with the `ini` as it appears in my question?

Comment: actually I will try to pursue this myself for a while. I don't want to ask you to "please fix this tutorial from 2012" (unless you are so inclined) ;-)